# object mapping/relation in ORM

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, object, relation

I have an object as below, which I populate from database, then to get the relationship for other object I just use clnt.cl.tolist() this will get me everything related to client in cl table :

```
Client clnt = Manager.Get_ByID(Id);
List<Cl> lstCl = clnt.Cl.ToList();
```

now if I have a list as first object how do i do this:

```
List<Client> clnt = Manager.Get_ListByClientID(Id);
List<Cl> lstCl = ???
```

**ALSO ::**

on second list how do I select just one record using linq??

Comment: That would sort of depend, would you just like a mishmash of _all_ clients' `Cl` property in one list, or...?

Comment: on the list all clients would have same CL.id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand what it is doing `List<Client> clnt = Manager.Get_ListByClientID(Id);` , but i mean you need something like this

```
List<Cl> lstCl = clnt.SelectMany(c=>c.Cl.ToList()).ToList();
```